# "Query input must contain at least one table or query" Error When Adding "INSERT INTO" Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

Expr1 finds the highest number in the row, and I want to store that in the "max num" field.

```
SELECT [impact test].num1, [impact test].num2, [impact test].num3, [impact test].[max num], 

IIf([num1]>[num2] And [num1]>[num3],[num1],
   IIf([num2]>[num1] And [num2]>[num3],[num2],
      IIf([num3]>[num1] And [num3]>[num2],[num3],"Error"))) AS Expr1, 

INSERT INTO [impact test] ([max num]) VALUES (Expr1) 

FROM [impact test];
```

The "Query input must contain at least one table or query" error highlights the "(" at the start of declaring the columns to store the values in. I've tried it a few different ways, such as

```
INSERT INTO [impact test].[max num] VALUES (Expr1)
INSERT INTO [impact test] (max num) VALUES (Expr1)
INSERT INTO [impact test].[max num] ([max num]) VALUES (Expr1)
INSERT INTO [impact test].[max num] (max num) VALUES (Expr1)
```

But none of those worked either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit for sample data and desired results:

```
num1   num2   num3   [max num]
 2      5      1         5
 3      4      6         6
 7      3      4         7
```

I just want to store the highest number from each row in the [max num] field. I tried looking up other ways of doing this but they all only max columns, not rows.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an `update` and no aggregation functons:

```
UPDATE [impact test] 
    SET [max num] = IIf([num1] > [num2] And [num1] > [num3], [num1],
                        IIf([num2] > [num1] And [num2] > [num3], [num2],
                            IIf([num3] > [num1] And [num3] > [num2], [num3], "Error")
                           )
                      );
```

You can simplify the logic to:

```
UPDATE [impact test] 
    SET [max num] = SWITCH([num1] > [num2] And [num1] > [num3], [num1],
                           [num2] > [num3], [num2],
                           [num3]
                          );
```

I don't think the `"Error"` value helps anything.  It just causes type confusion.

Comment: I tried using this, and got the same error in the same spot :/

Thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: @Roland . . . I changed the answer to what you probably really want.

Comment: There's a "Syntax error (missing operator)", highlighting "[impact test]", which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me either.

Comment: @Roland . . . Perhaps there is something before it in the script or a bad character.

Comment: If I take out the problem statement, everything works fine with no errors.